# How to write a service class to return any implementation class object which implements interface

Tags: java, spring

I have a requirement to update number of records into a table in a single call from Java program. Simply it is JDBC batch update.

For this, I have this following code snippet at interface and implementation which is perfectly working.

```
interface TableABatchUpdater extends Logic<TableADTO> {
   void updateBatch(List<TableADTO> list)
}

class TableABatchUpdaterImpl extends AbstractLogic<TableADTO> implements TableABatchUpdater {
   @Autowired DAOClass dao;

   TableABatchUpdaterImpl(){
     super("TableA");
   }

   @Override
    void updateBatch(List<TableADTO> list) {
        dao.updateBatch(list)
    }

}
interface TableBBatchUpdater extends Logic<TableBDTO> {
   void updateBatch(List<TableBDTO> list)
}

class TableBBatchUpdaterImpl extends AbstractLogic<TableBDTO> implements TableBBatchUpdater {
   @Autowired DAOClass dao;

   TableBBatchUpdaterImpl(){
     super("TableB");
   }

   @Override
    void updateBatch(List<TableBDTO> list) {
        dao.updateBatch(list)
    }

}

interface TableCBatchUpdater extends Logic<TableCDTO> {
   void updateBatch(List<TableCDTO> list)
}

class TableACatchUpdaterImpl extends AbstractLogic<TableCDTO> implements TableABatchUpdater {
   @Autowired DAOClass dao;

   TableCBatchUpdaterImpl(){
     super("TableC");
   }

   @Override
    void updateBatch(List<TableCDTO> list) {
        dao.updateBatch(list)
    }

}


public class MyServiceClass {

  @Autowired TableABatchUpdater tableA;
  @Autowired TableBBatchUpdater tableB;
  @Autowired TableCBatchUpdater tableC;

  public void updateTables() {
     tableA.updateBatch(tableAList);
     tableB.updateBatch(tableBList);
     tableC.updateBatch(tableCList);
   }

}
```

The problem here is, when I would like to add batch update statements for another table called `"TableD"`, MyServiceClass class dependencies are increasing and the complexity is very high interms of unit testing..etc. So, I tried to use one interface instead of independent interface for each table as follows. But, still I have to write many implementation classes for each table which I don't want.

```
interface BatchUpdater extends Logic<?> {
       void updateBatch(List<?> list)
}
```

I tried to write the implementations by using factory and composite patterns. But, none of them worked out.

Is there any other way in Spring to write a separate service class which will return as the following.

```
public class MyServiceClass {

    @Autowired BatchUpdaterService batchUpdaterService;

    public void updateTables() {
        batchUpdaterService.getTableUpdater("TableA").updateBatch(tableAList);
        batchUpdaterService.getTableUpdater("TableB").updateBatch(tableBList);
        batchUpdaterService.getTableUpdater("TableC").updateBatch(tableCList);
    }

}
```

Any response is highly appreciated

Comment: To understand , there are multiple implemenations of `BatchUpdater` and the requirement here is to programmatically call the corresponding implemenation based on the type of list , is it ? Also ,  within `MyServiceClass.updateTables()` how is `TableA`  bean and `tableAList` mapped ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use a factory pattern with HashMap and reflections to instantiate like

```
public static class Factory{
    final static HashMap<String,Class<? extends MyAbstractClass>> supportedVersions = new HashMap<>();
    static{

        supportedVersions.put("v1", ClassV1.class);
        supportedVersions.put("v2", ClassV2.class);
        
    }

    public static MyAbstractClass getInstanceFor(String type) {
        try {
            return supportedVersions.get(type)
                    .getConstructor().newInstance("params");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new CustomException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Something went wrong");
        } catch (InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new CustomException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Unsupported Version");

        }
    }
}
```